# reference in argument of a function

Tags: c++, reference

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Vector{
int sz; // no of elements
double * elem; // pointer to elements
};

void vector_init(Vector& v, int s){ // & indicates that we pass v by non-const reference
v.elem = new double[s]; // allocate an array of s doubles
v.sz = s;
}

double read_and_sum(int s){
Vector v;
vector_init(v,s);
for (int i=0; i!=s; i++)
cin>>v.elem[i]; // read into elements
double sum = 0;
for (int i=0; i!=s; i++)
sum += v.elem[i];

return sum;
}

int main(){
cout << read_and_sum(4) <<endl;
}
```

Why do we pass `v` by a non-const reference in the function `vector_init`? From what I understand, one can access the argument without making a copy of it by using references. But why cant we pass the `Vector v` directly to the function (meaning `void vector_init(Vector v, int s)`)? I tried and the compiler raised an error ('Segmentation fault (core dumped)
').

Comment: If you pass `const Vector& v`, you won't be able to modify `v`. If you pass `Vector v`, `v` would be just copied and all things you've done with `v` in `vector_init` wouldn't be available when you operate with `v` in `read_and_sum`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so segmentation fault happens when you want to write in a read-only memory location. When you passes the vector by reference, as you said it won't be a copy of it, so if you modify it, it'll change where you declared that variable. But if you pass it as non-reference, it'll make a copy of it, so when you allocate memory for the elements, it'll allocate that to the copy Vector, therefore the variable v will have a null pointer for its elem variable. When you try to read elements to that, it'll be pointing nothing, so this is why you're getting the segmentation error.

Answer (score 1):

> But why cant we pass the Vector v directly to the function (meaning void vector_init(Vector v, int s))? I tried and the compiler raised an error ('Segmentation fault (core dumped) ').

If you pass by value `vector_init(Vector v, int s)` then a copy of original `v` from the caller is passed to the callee (vector_init). There would be no change in original `v`, ie there are no memory allocation done to it, and so it segfault when you tried to access the unallocated item in the for loop `v.elem[i];`

Answer (score 1):

When you pass it as a const reference you are not able to modify it, when you just do `void vector_init(Vector v, int s)` you are passing a copy of it, so you are creating a temporal v. When you do `Vector& v` you are using the same v that in main function, so all changes done will be saved.

Answer (score 0):

So what you are asking is; why, if we make a copy and change the copy, does it not affect the original? The answer is obvious I think.

```
void vector_init(Vector v, int s){
    v.elem = new double[s]; 
    v.sz = s;
}

Vector v;
vector_init(v,s); // here v is copied and the copy is changed by vector_init

for (int i=0; i!=s; i++)
    cin>>v.elem[i]; // here we use the original v, which has not been changed
```

If you use a reference in `vector_init` then no copy is made and the `v` in the calling function is modified.

Answer (score 0):

A segfault happens because, when you pass `v` to `vector_init` by value, what happens is that the function actually gets a *copy* of `v` rather that `v` itself.

That means that `vector_init` doesn't actually initializes `v`, but it rathers initializes its own copy of `v` (which by the way gets destroyed when the function finishes, leading to a memory leak).

With `v` being uninitialized, `read_and_sum` operates on it, but because it tries to access the elements of the also uninitialized `v.elem` (which by then points to a very likely forbidden part of the memory), the program crashes and you get a segmentation fault.

The solution is obviously pass by reference (or by pointer if you want to), then `vector_init` can actually initialize the `v` you pass to it, hence everything works fine.

As a side note, I believe that a `destroy_vector` function which calls `delete[] v.elem` should be implemented so, when you're done with `v`, you can deallocate the memory that `v.elem` points to, as for how it is now there is definitely a memory leak going on there.